# Flat List Not Scrolling in TabView (React Native Elements)

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am using the `React-Native-Elements` Library to create tabs.
Under the TabView, I have a `FlatList`, the list appears but it is not able to scroll, I have tried implementing `flex: 1` as well as wrapping the FlatList in a `ScrollView`.
The code is below shows the `TabView` along with the rendering of the `TabView.Item, View and FlatList`.

```
<TabView value={this.state.index} onChange={this.handleChange}>
          <TabView.Item style={{width: deviceWidth}}>
            <View style={{flex: 1}}>
              <Text style={styles.text}> Blockchain News </Text>
              <FlatList
                // eslint-disable-next-line react-native/no-inline-styles
                style={styles.bgColor}
                data={this.state.articles}
                renderItem={({item}) => <DataItem article={item} />}
                keyExtractor={item => item.url}
                refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
                onRefresh={this.handleRefresh.bind(this)}
              />
            </View>
          </TabView.Item>
```

Comment: Can you create an Expo Snack?

Answer (score 1):

I came across similar issue, try making the DataItem element with TouchableOpacity rather with normal view. This worked for me

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31487076)